# Can I use LOAD DATA INFILE to insert all file data into one column?

Tags: php, mysql, large-files, load-data-infile

We're storing report files in a mysql database table. Our current implementation looks something like this:

```
// File was generated and placed on the disk, now we're going
// to store it in the database
$file = file_get_contents($path);

$report->csv_data = $file;
$report->save(); // UPDATE reports SET csv_data = ... WHERE id = ?
```

Well, this causes out of memory errors with larger, several hundred megabyte reports.  I tried using PDO::PARAM_LOB, but that doesn't work, it loads the whole file into memory.

So I was trying to use mysql's LOAD DATA INFILE to insert the file, but it's generally used for parsing and mass importing data.  **I don't want to parse the report data, I just need the entire file contents put into a single column on a single row in the table.** This is something I was tinkering around with:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/web/reportTest.csv'
INTO TABLE report.reports
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY ''
(csv_data)
```

I'm trying to set the delimiters to some character that will never be in the result set, and only fill the csv_data column, which sort of works, but seems hacky, and is driving up the auto incrememnter with failed rows.  I just  can't find any other examples of people doing this, so any help would be appreciated.  Also, if someone knows of a better way to accomplish this, I'm all ears.

EDIT: My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `report` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `date` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `uindex` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `csv_filename` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `csv_data` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `delivery_schedule` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL,
    `saved_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `saved_id` (`saved_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `date_idx` (`date`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=678526
;
```

Comment: What is your structure database ? If your csv is like this : "bla,bla,blou,...,[+255 char],..." and your column is varchar(255) it's normal if it don't work.
Note : you need to have lines terminated by the right character if you don't want have all the csv in 1 column AND 1 line. Can you share your .csv and the structure table ?

Comment: *I'm trying to set the delimiters to some character that will never be in the result set* Have you tried the same with a "small" file (1-2 Mnytes, for example)?

Comment: @Xenofexs That's exactly what I'm trying to do, load the whole csv file into one column in one row.  The csv data and structure will vary, they are just different user generated reports in our system.  csv_data is a LONGTEXT column.

Comment: @Akina No, not yet.  I've just done a few tests with real reports.

Comment: If you just want to store the contents of the whole file in one column, just use `INSERT`.

Comment: @BillKarwin That kills my memory, doing the whole thing at once.  I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

Comment: [LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) ?

Comment: @BillKarwin  Huh... I'll check that out.

Comment: Why does storing a file that is "several hundred megabytes" in MySQL seem like a good idea to you? I can't imagine a situation where file storage would not be a better answer.

Comment: @miken32 Because we have multiple servers, load balancing, and this is a legacy system that I can't re-tool right now :)  All of our documents and generated reports get stored in the centralized database.

Comment: @BillKarwin LOAD_FILE would work perfectly for me, except that the database is on a separate server.  I would have to get the file over to its filesystem first, which I don't think would be practical, especially since we're talking about moving to RDS.

Comment: You may be able to use PDO to bind a parameter to a filehandle to a stream. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php for examples. I've never tried this with the MySQL PDO driver, it's possible it's only implemented in certain other drivers.

Comment: FWIW, LOAD DATA INFILE also reads files on the database server. You'd have to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE if you want to read a file on the app side.